# Show VIEW attachments in a block

Tags: views

i have a page-view that shows all avatars from the community.
This view has an exposed filter.

This community-view has two attachment-views:
- most comments
- best authors

Now i want to have the attachment-views shown in the sidebar as a block.

How can i handle the attachment like a block?

Thanx Michi

Answer (score 0):

You can create a block-view display with no content and then attach those attachment-view to the block-view display. This may be a possible hack if i understand you correctly.

Comment: But the exposed filter won`t work in the block, right?

Comment: I am able to see the "expose this filter" checkbox. Possibly it can work, please try and confirm back.